# Degree location and mapkit

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mapkit

12.2N 109.2W

Given this location, how would I find a point on a mkmapkit map?  Does it have to be converted to lat/long? Little bit lost about this...

Comment: Keep in mind that for South and West the sign should be reversed.  So 12.2N = 12.2 but 109.2W = -109.2.  So parse your input for 'S' and 'W' and change the sign accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location you describe is already a latitude/longitude:

Latitude : 12.2 degrees North
Longitude : 109.2 degrees West.

You can set the *coordinate* property on a [MKAnnotation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) delegate to set a pin on a *MKMapKit* at that point.